# iTunes artwork data as html image

Tags: php, image, applescript, itunes

I'm playing around with Applescript in PHP, trying to make my own iTunes remote.

Now I want to add the album covers to the remote.
I know I can get the artwork data from iTunes to PHP:

```
$ph = popen( "osascript", "w" );
fwrite( $ph, $artwork=`osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to data of artwork 1 of current track'` );
fclose( $ph );
```

Applescript Editor returns this line:

```
«data JPEGFFD8FFE000104A4649460001010100...*more numbers*...2CEA245A3FFD9»
```

I thought

```
<img src="data:base64,<?=$artwork;?>" />
```

should do the trick...

I'm not even sure if applescript returns raw JPG data since iTunes uses .itc (iTunes cover) files itself. Although the data returned starts with JPEG... "«data JPEGFFD..."

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried an image header?

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image.jpg" );
```